# Find the marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution, marginal-distribution

Suppose that $(U,V)$ has the following joint pdf:
$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=\exp(-\theta u-\theta^{-1}v)$$
, where $u\geq0$, $v\geq0$, $\theta>0$. Define $X=UV$ and $Y=U/V$. Find the marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$.

With transformation, I got $U=\sqrt{XY}$ and $V=\sqrt{X/Y}$ and the absolute value of Jacob is $1/2Y$. Then, the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\exp(-\theta \sqrt{XY}-\theta^{-1}\sqrt{X/Y})1/2Y, X,Y>0.$$

But I am not sure how to get the marginal pdf?

Thank you!

Comment: you found the Jacobbian determinant.  Do not forget to use it.

Comment: ooh, I miss this part.

Comment: Unless you are asked to find the marginals from the joint distribution, you might try finding them directly noting that $U,V$ are independent exponential variables. The distribution of $U/V$ can be readily recognised as a scaled $F$ density but not the other one.

Comment: That's an easier way. I'll try it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729119/321264

Answer (score 1):

As you had found, pdf of $(X,Y)$ is

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2y}\exp\left[-\left(\theta\sqrt{xy}+\frac{1}{\theta}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}\right)\right]\,\mathbf1_{x>0,y>0}$$

So pdf of $Y$ is

\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=\frac{1}{2y}\int_0^\infty \exp\left[-\left(\frac{\theta^2y+1}{\theta\sqrt{y}}\right)\sqrt{x}\right]\,dx\,\mathbf1_{y>0}
\\&=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^\infty te^{-\alpha t}\,dt\,\mathbf1_{y>0} \tag{*}
\\&=\frac{1}{y\alpha^2}\mathbf1_{y>0}
\end{align}

In $(*)$ we substituted $t^2=x$ and $\alpha=\frac{\theta^2y+1}{\theta\sqrt{y}}(>0)$.

That is, $$f_Y(y)=\left(\frac{\theta}{\theta^2y+1}\right)^2\mathbf1_{y>0}$$

Indeed since $U$ and $V$ are independent exponential variables, it can be verified that $\theta^2Y\sim F_{2,2}$, an F distribution with $(2,2)$ degrees of freedom.

And substituting $u^2=y$, density of $X$ is given by

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u}\exp\left[-\left(\theta\sqrt{x}u+\frac{\sqrt x}{\theta u}\right)\right]\,du\,\mathbf1_{x>0}$$

The above can be rewritten as $$f_X(x)=2K_0(2\sqrt{x})\,\mathbf1_{x>0}\,,$$

where $K_0(\cdot)$ is a [Modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

Notably the distribution of $X$ is independent of $\theta$.

Comment: $f_Y$ should be $1/(\theta^{-1} + \theta y)^2 \, [y > 0]$.

Comment: Thanks for noticing.

Comment: It may help to notice that $UV=X_1X_2$ where $X_1=\theta U,X_2=\frac1{\theta}V$ are both Exp(1). This also explains why distribution of $UV$ is free of $\theta$.