# Distribution of $XY$ and $\frac{X}{Y}$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

The joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is given:

$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=e^{-(\theta x +\frac{y}{\theta})}$, $0<x,y<\infty$

Find the distribution of $U=XY$ and $V=\frac{X}{Y}$. Also find the conditional pdf of $V$ given $U=u$.

I have transformed $(X,Y)\rightarrow (U,V)$, and found the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ as the following:

$f_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2v}e^{-(\theta \sqrt {uv}+\frac{1}{\theta}\sqrt {\frac{u}{v}})}$, $0<u,v<\infty$

But I cannot find the marginal pdf of $U$ and $V$ and the conditional pdf of $V$ given $U=u$.

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211723/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Okay. It helped me a lot. Can you tell me how to find the conditional pdf of $V$ given $U=u$? Is it simply the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ divided by the marginal pdf of $U$? Because, doing this does not give me a compact form of $V|U$, it is just a ratio of two pdfs. Should I leave it like that, or is there any other way to find the conditional distribution?

Comment: $f_{V\mid U}(v\mid u)=\frac{f_{U,V}(u,v)}{f_U(u)}$. I don't think this simplifies much.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Okay then, thanks.