# Compute mean value of the exponential of product of 2 exponential variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I have to compute $E[e^{vS}]$, where $v$ and $S$ are two independent RVs exponentially distributed with different parameters, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$.

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729119/product-of-two-random-variables-that-has-exponential-distribution.) I started computing $Y = vS$, but then it is hard to continue with the integral and $e^Y$

How can I solve it?

**EDIT 1**

In particular, I have to compute the mean completion time $C$ of processes in a queuing system with priorities:
$$E[C] = (E[e^{vS}]-1)*({E[D]+ \frac{1}{v}})$$ so $v$ is an interarrival time, $S$ is a service time and $D$ is the duration of the process with higher priority.

**EDIT 2**
The paper that I am studying is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wx25iludgchit14/A%20Waiting%20Line%20with%20Interrupted%20Service%2C%20Including%20Priorities.pdf?dl=0), in I am trying to solve $E[C]$ and $E[C^2 ]$ on page 8. In the start pages, there is the therminolgy used

Comment: Did you mean $C=(e^{vS}-1)(D+1/v),\,E[C]=E[(e^{vS}-1)(D+1/v)]$?

Comment: No, $C$ in the paper that I am studying is $C = S + \sum_{i=0}^{N} S'(i) + \sum_{i=0}^{N} D(i) $, where $S, S'$ and $D$ are times.

Comment: So where does $v$ get involved? To be honest, I can't see why multiplying exponential variables would be part of a model of how long anything takes.

Comment: I am trying to study paper that talks about this stuff. The paper is https://www.dropbox.com/s/wx25iludgchit14/A%20Waiting%20Line%20with%20Interrupted%20Service%2C%20Including%20Priorities.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Yes, added. We can also talk through a chat..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99954/discussion-between-linofex-and-j-g).

Comment: Rather than chatting only with me, I recommend you edit your question to quote relevant equations from the paper, then say exactly which calculation you're attempting and how it relates to the paper, and where you've become stuck. You might gets lots of help after that/

Comment: Yes, I just thought that instead of writing many comments we could resolve privately and then post the correct answer. The information about the paper is important to be added, anyway,

Answer (score 0):

Your mean is$$\int_0^\infty dv\int_0^\infty dS\lambda_1\lambda_2\exp(vS-\lambda_1v-\lambda_2S)=\int_0^\infty dv\int_0^\infty dS\lambda_1\lambda_2\exp((S-\lambda_1)(v-\lambda_2)-\lambda_1\lambda_2).$$The region $S>\lambda_1,\,v>\lambda_2$ makes an infinite contribution $\lambda_1\lambda_2\exp(-\lambda_1\lambda_2)\int_0^\infty da\int_0^\infty db\exp(ab)$ with $a:=S-\lambda_1,\,b:=\lambda_2$, so the final result is $\infty$.

Comment: But I have to compute a mean time of a process, that should be finite. I edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Making a start:$$\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{xy}\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}e^{-\lambda_{1}x}e^{-\lambda_{2}y}dxdy=\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda_{2}y}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x\left(y-\lambda_{1}\right)}dxdy$$

Now observe that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x\left(y-\lambda_{1}\right)}dx=\infty$
if $y>\lambda_{1}$ and consequently  $\mu=\infty$.

Comment: But I have to compute a mean time of a process, that should be finite. I edited the question with more information.